# Airflow DockerOperator, how to add a volume to a container

Tags: docker, airflow, docker-volume, dockeroperator

I have a serie of tasks that is supposed to spin up containers and run a python script in them.
I however need to mount the volume which contains the python code...

After running into many errors I found out adding a volume is not supported anymore, and now a Mount object has to be specified:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/15843

My code looks like this for the task:

```
from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator
from docker.types import Mount

code_dir = Mount(target='/SRC',
                     source='/SRC/code',
                     type='bind')

task_name = DockerOperator(
            task_id=f"task_{task_name}",
            image='python-multi-purpose:latest',
            container_name=task_name,
            mount=[code_dir],
            api_version='auto',
            auto_remove=True,
            command=command,
            docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
            network_mode="bridge",
            dag=dag
        )
```

Unfortunately I am running in the same exact error I was receiving when using volumes=[list]:

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to DockerOperator (task_id: task_yh_get_info.A). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'mount': [{'Target': '/SRC', 'Source': '/SRC/code', 'Type': 'bind', 'ReadOnly': False}]}
```

Would anyone be able to provide the syntax and a logical explanation of how to make this work?

Alternatively, any suggestion on how to approach this? keeping in mind I have Airflow running inside a container

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Another answer then (if you have the latest docker provider):

`mount` -> `mounts`.

You have typo in parameter name: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html

Comment: Ok so when this happens I always tell myself I need to take a break and look at my code the next day. But I have been stuck on this for a week so what am I going to do!!!! :D

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have new errors unfortunately but at least its trying to do the mount now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem you had that there was a bug in Docker Provider 2.0.0 which prevented Docker Operator to run with Docker-In-Docker solution. It's been solved in 2.1.0

You need to upgrade to the latest Docker Provider 2.1.0 https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/index.html#id1

You can do it by extending the image as described in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#extending-the-image with - for example - this docker file:

```
FROM apache/airflow
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir apache-airflow-providers-docker==2.1.0
```

The operator will work out-of-the-box in this case with "fallback" mode (and Warning message), but you can also disable the mount that causes the problem. More explanation from the https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html

However if you have to remember though, that when you use docker-in-docker (and mount docker socket) the behaviour of "bind" mount might be not what you are expecting. It will actually mount the "host" volumes to the new container run by DockerOperator, it will not mount folders from one container to the other. But I believe this is what you wanted to do anyway - if that's the case then the new version of Docker Provider should fix your problems.

Also - if that still does not solve your problem you can always downgrade the DockerOperator to previous version before the "volume/mount" change.

Comment: Thank you Jarek, unfortunately I alredy have the latest version of apache-airflow-providers-docker. I can try downgrading and using "volume" however that had a bug which made it non usable therefore I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: @Luke_V I had a similiar issue, using the pip command as described here installed the package in the /root directory and the default installation is using /home/airflow, once I changed that it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you @MCSH, my issue was actually the typo....sad I know...